# Can I find customisable human models for my animations?

Tags: modeling

I want to make 3D animations in Blender, and I would like to have pre-made models, but I couldn't find customisable ones. I would like to customise the characters, namely their age (I want to make a child), skin tone, eye color, hair color, and probably other traits. I also want to give them clothes of my design, and giving some of them clothes with existing designs can also be useful. Of course, they should be rigged, and having some pre-made animations would also be a plus. They should also be foc and without fees for using the site. Is there a site that offers that?

I've searched for sites that offer models, but none of them seem to say that they are customisable.

Comment: Have you tired the Make Human add-on? it's free.

Comment: Or try [MB-Lab](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/), a Blender addon that creates humanoid characters